# Is it possible to retrieve a custom Object with @Formula annotation?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to retrieve a custom Object with @Formula annotation? I would like to retrieve the code and the description of a specific table in one of my entities:

```sql
    @Formula(value = "(SELECT s.cod_setor AS code, s.descricao_setor AS description"
            + " FROM service.sector s LEFT JOIN service.employee e "
            + " ON (s.cpf = e.cpf) "
            + " WHERE e.cpf=cpf)")
    private SectorDTO sector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `@PostLoad` usage.

```java
@Formula(value = "(SELECT concat(s.cod_setor, '_', s.descricao_setor)"
            + " FROM service.sector s LEFT JOIN service.employee e "
            + " ON (s.cpf = e.cpf) "
            + " WHERE e.cpf=cpf)")
// select multiple fields as one string where values are divided by '_'
private String sectorFormula;

@Transient
private SectorDTO sector;

@PostLoad
private void onLoad() {
    String[] parts = sectorFormula.split("_");
    this.sector = new SectorDTO(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ty my friend! It worked pretty well.